# Unresolved external symbol during linking CUDA program with Thrust

Tags: c++, cuda, thrust

I created a simple program using some `Thrust` library functions, but recieve a link error *Unresolved external symbol* on templated function. I use VS2010.

Here is my code.

**func.cuh**

```
#pragma once

#include <thrust/host_vector.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>

struct F1 {
    template <typename Tuple> 
    __host__ __device__ 
    void operator()(Tuple arg) {        
        thrust::get<1>(arg) = (-1) * thrust::get<0>(arg);
    } 
};

struct F2 {
    template <typename Tuple>   
    __host__ __device__     
    void operator()(Tuple arg) { 
        thrust::get<1>(arg) = thrust::get<0>(arg) + 1.0;
    } 
};

template <typename Functor> thrust::host_vector<double> evalFunc(Functor func, thrust::host_vector<double> point) {
    size_t space_dim = point.size();

    thrust::device_vector<double> dev_point(space_dim);
    thrust::device_vector<double> dev_result(space_dim);
    thrust::host_vector<double> result(space_dim);

    dev_point = point;
    thrust::for_each(thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(dev_point.begin(), dev_result.begin())),
                     thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(dev_point.end(), dev_result.end())),
                     func);     
    result = dev_result;

    return result; 
}
```

**operations.h**

```
#pragma once

thrust::host_vector<double> computeFunction(thrust::device_vector<double> v);
```

**operations.cu**

```
#include "operations.h"
#include "func.cuh"

thrust::host_vector<double> computeFunction(HostVector v) {
    return evalFunc(F1(), v);
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <thrust/host_vector.h>
#include "operations.h"

int main(void) {
    ...
    // some code that creates and fills the vector v 
    ...

    thrust::host_vector<double> r = computeFunction(v);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

All files are being successfully compiled but I get an error during linking

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class thrust::host_vector<double,class std::allocator<double> > __cdecl computeFunction(class thrust::device_vector<double,class thrust::device_malloc_allocator<double> >)" (?computeFunction@@YA?AV?$host_vector@NV?$allocator@N@std@@@thrust@@V?$device_vector@NV?$device_malloc_allocator@N@thrust@@@2@@Z) referenced in function main
```

Why?

Comment: Thrust code usually is compiled via the `nvcc` compiler using the file extension `.cu`  I'm not sure it will work properly with your `main.cpp`.  What happens if you change `main.cpp` to `main.cu` ?

Comment: @Robert, the same error. And all specific CUDA code is in the `operations.cu` file, so I thought that everything sould've been fine :)

Comment: The problem's solved! It was my fault - different parameter's types in definition of `computeFunction` and its implementation. Can't realize how I could make such a silly mistake!

Comment: Please post an answer describing the fix, so we can close this question.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The problem's solved! It was my fault - different parameter's types in definition of computeFunction and its implementation.